# error: libcurl >= 7.22.0 library and headers are required with support for https (for R 3.4.1)

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I tried to install R 3.4.1 on my computer. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I have R 3.3.2 already. I typed `./configure`, but first I got this error message:

> error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available

I found some helps in stackoverflow, so I tried to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
```

and use one of three libcurl4-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-nss-dev
```

Maybe I fixed the first problem, but I couldn't install yet. I got this error message:

> error: libcurl >= 7.22.0 library and headers are required with support for https

Could anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: side note - how are you trying to install R - did you follow these steps https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

Comment: ... and what happened. (im guessing it didnt work as you are now trying to build from source??, or...?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
First, I tried to use
deb http://cran.nexr.com/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
, but it didn't work because of "deb: command not found"
So, I also used
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
but I got "r-base is already the newest version (3.2.3-4)." message.
I want to install 3.4.1 version of R, so I downloaded R-3.4.1.tar.gz from https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/
I unzipped it using "tar -xvzf R-3.4.1.tar.gz", and typed cd R-3.4.1 and ./configure.

Comment: okay, from the link above , in the terminal try : `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9` , then edit sources.list `sudo gedit  /etc/apt/sources.list` and add line `deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/` , save and close. Then `apt-get update`, then `apt-get install r-base r-base-dev`

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: May I ask one more question? I updated my R to R 3.4.1, but in my R studio, I still use R version 3.3.2. I'd be grateful if you let me know how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome. Im not sure  - there is this: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R. But first, have you also updated / re installed rstudio?

Comment: I use "the newest version of RStudio", but I didn't re-install it. I will check it. Thanks for your kind helps!

Comment: It was a problem of Anaconda. The Anaconda folder was upstream of any $PATH, my R and rstudio used Anaconda's R (older version). So I typed "export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=/usr/bin/R" to fix it. Thank you so much for your helps!